# Locking Strategy for Millions of Linked Lists + Multithreading (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm

I have a C program with 16-million-odd linked lists, and 4 worker threads.

No two threads should work on the same linked list at the same time, otherwise they might be modifying it simultaneously, which would be bad.

My initial naive solution was something like this:

```
int linked_lists_locks[NUM_LINKED_LISTS];
for (i=0; i< NUM_LINKED_LISTs; i++)
   linked_lists_locks[i] = 0;
```

then later, in a section executed by each thread as it works:

```
while ( linked_lists_locks[some_list] == 1 ) {
   /* busy wait */
}
linked_lists_locks[some_list] = 1;  // mark it locked lock it
/* work with the list */
linked_lists_locks[some_list] = 0;
```

However, with 4 threads and ~250,000,000 operations I quickly got into cases where both threads did the same "is it locked" simultaneously and problems ensued.  Smart people here would have seen that coming :-)

I've looked at some locking algorithms like Dekker's and Peterson's, but they seem to be more "lock this section of code" whereas what I'm looking for is "lock this variable".  I suspect that if I lock the "work with the list" section of code, everything slows to a crawl because then only one thread can work (though I haven't tried it).  Essentially, each worker's job is limited to doing some math and populating these lists.  Cases where each thread wants to work on the same list simultaneously are rare, btw - only a few thousand times out of 250M operations, but they do happen.

Is there an algorithm or approach for implementing locks on many variables as opposed to sections of code?  This is C (on Linux if that matters) so synchronized array lists, etc. from Java/C#/et al are not available.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Comment: I do not believe that you have 16 million linked lists. If you do there is a more fundamental problem with the algorithm.

Comment: Try to use more arrays or vectors (perhaps make linked lists of arrays). But you don't show any code, so we cannot help much.

Comment: Use pthread facilities, notably `pthread_mutex_lock` ... Avoid busy spinlocks. (and you need [atomic int](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)s, not plain `int`s, for your `linked_lists_locks`). Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Comment: Your locking seems kind of broken. What happens if thread 1 fetches locks[i], gets descheduled and thread 2 fetches and sets locks[i]. Imo thread 1 will also enter the crit section, but please point out how you prevent that, if you do. I think you should do atomic compare and set here.

Answer (score 3):

It would be useful to know more about how your application is organized, but here are a few ideas about how to approach the problem.

1. A common solution for "synchronized" objects is to assign a [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) to each object. Before working on an object, the thread needs to acquire the object's mutex; when it is done, it releases the mutex. That's simple and effective, but if you really have 16 million lockable objects, it's a lot of overhead. More seriously, if two tasks really try to work on the same object at the same time, one of them will end up sleeping until the other one releases the lock. If there was something else the tasks might have been doing, the opportunity has been lost.
2. A simple solution to the first problem -- the overhead of 16 million mutexes -- is to use a small vector of mutexes and a hash function which maps each object to one mutex. If you only have four tasks, and you used a vector of, say, 1024 mutexes, you will occasionally end up with a thread needlessly waiting for another thread, but it won't be very common.
3. If lock contention really turns out to be a problem and it is possible to vary the order in which work is one, a reasonable model is a workqueue. Here, when a thread wants to do something, it takes a task off the workqueue, attempts to lock the task's object (using `trylock` instead of `lock`), and if that works, does the task. If the lock fails, it just puts the task back on the workqueue and grabs another one. To avoid workqueue lock contention, it's common for threads to grab a handful of tasks instead of one; each thread then manages its own subqueue. Tuning the various parameters in this solution requires knowing at least a bit about the characteristics of the tasks. (There is a kind of race condition in this solution, but it doesn't matter; it just means that occasionally tasks will be deferred unnecessarily. But they should always get executed eventually.)

Comment: Nice and clear reply!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an atomic test and set operation.  Unfortunately, you may need to use an assembly routine if your compiler doesn't have a built-in for that.  See this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely forced to use this many lists, and you have very few threads, you might not want to lock the lists, but allow the worker-threads to claim a single list at a time. In this case you need a structure to store the number of the list currently held and the list must not be aliased with another number.

Since you didn't seem to use any library I'll add some pseudo-code to clarify my idea:

```
/*
 * list_number, the number of the list you want to lock
 * my_id, the id of the thread trying to lock this list
 * mutex, the mutex used to control locking the lists
 * active_lists, array containing the lists currently held by the threads
 * num_threads, size of the array and also number of threads
 */
void lock_list(int list_number, int my_id, some_mutex *mutex, 
    atomic_int *active_lists, size_t num_threads) {
    int ok = 0;
    int i;
    while (true){ //busy wait to claim the lock
    //first check if anyone seems to hold the list we want.
    //Do this in a non-locking way to avoid lock contention
        while (!ok){
            ok = 1;
            for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i){
                if (active_lists[i].load() == list_number && i != my_id){
                    ok = 0;
                    /*
                     * we have to restart - potential to optimize
                     * at this point, you could delay the work on this list
                     * to do some other work
                     */
                    break; 
                }
            }
        }
        while(try_to_lock(mutex));
        //rerun the check to see if anyone has taken the list in the meantime
        // ok == 1 at this point
        for (i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i){
            if (active_lists[i].load() == list_number && i != my_id){
               ok = 0;
               break;
            }
        }
        //this must not be set from anywhere else!
        if (ok) active_lists[my_id].store(list_number);
        unlock(mutex);
        //if we noticed someone claimed the list, go back to the beginning.
        if (ok) break; 
    }
}
```

There are a few constraints to the pseudo-types. some_mutex obviously has to be a mutex. What I call atomic_int here must somehow support fetching its latest value form main memory to prevent you from seeing old values, which are cached. Same goes for the store: it must not be cached core-locally before being written. Using a regular int and using lfence, sfence and/or mfence may work as well.

There are obviously some trade-offs here, where the main one is probably memory vs speed. This example will create contention at the single mutex used to store which list you have locked, so it will scale poorly with a large number of threads, but well with a large number of lists. If lists are claimed infrequently this would work well even at a larger number of threads. The advantage is that the storage requirement depends mainly on the number of threads. You have to pick a storage type which can hold a number equivalent to the maximum number of lists though.

I am not sure what exactly your scenario is, but recently lock-free lists have also gained some momentum. With the introduction of advanced support for lock-free code in C11 and C++11, there have been a few working (as in not shown to be broken) examples around. [Herb Sutter gave a talk on how to do this in C++11.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs) It is C++, but he discusses the relevant points of writing a lock free singly linked list, which are also true for plain old C. You can also try to find an existing implementation, but you should inspect it carefully because this is kind of bleeding edge stuff. However using lock-free lists would erase the need to lock at all.